iptables-translate: translate iptables -m set --match-set to nftables
Is there a way to automatically translate --match-set iptables rules to match on a named nftables set with the same name? iptables-translate doesn't seem to be able to do this, which somewhat makes sense since the two aren't strictly compatible
